# Jquery..I want to search within my search results

Tags: jquery

I have a webpage and I can get selected checkboxes. now what I want to do is to select checkboxes within above selection using id which I get using this.id. But no luck. Not sure where I am going wrong here. Here is my function for same.

```
function GetSelectedChks()
{
    var doc = document.forms["form1"];
    var valarr=[];
    var ids = "";
    var selIndexes = "";
    $(":checked").each(function(index)
    {   
        if(this.name=='selChk' && ids!=this.id)
        {
            ids = this.id;
            $(eval('#"+ids+"')).each(function(index1){selIndexes=selIndexes+"-"+this.value});
            valarr.push(ids+"~"+selIndexes);
            selIndexes = "";
        }
    });
    doc.selChk.value = valarr;
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `eval` there? And why use plain JS for selecting the form but jQuery for everything else? Also, not sure what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: `$(eval('"#"+ids+""')) === $('#'+ids)`

Comment: You want to select the checked checkboxes? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Also [id's should be unique](http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/WCAG20/tests/test185.html) on the page.

Comment: My checkbox group is dynamically generated. Some can have same ids.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari - I tried your approach.no luck!!

Comment: Not and be **valid HTML** they can't. This breaks Jquery and the HTML standards

Comment: @Liam. ok. can I have a custom attribute instead of id and use that as a selector?

Comment: In this case can I have partial id selector? like $("#Id-*")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to suggest that do not use mixed js/jquery, everything can do with either js or jquery itself.

Your question is unclear on what is your goal. From what I understand, you are trying to get all the checked checkboxes in 1 field. But I don't get it why did you put it in your checkbox value again.

Anyway, please find the code at fiddle that I was trying to achieve what I assumed you want to achieve. DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/gZZF3/

HTML:

```
<form name="form1">
    <input type="checkbox" id="1" name="selChk" value="test 1"  /> test 1
    <input type="checkbox" id="2" name="selChk" value="test 2" />test 2
    <input type="checkbox" id="3" value="test 3"  />test 3
    <input type="checkbox" id="4" value="test 4"/>test 4
    <input type="hidden" value="" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
function GetSelectedChks() {
    var doc = document.forms["form1"];
    var valarr=[];
    var ids = "";
    var selIndexes = "";
    $(":checked").each(function(index)
    {   
        if(this.name=='selChk' && ids!=this.id)
        {
            ids = this.id;
            $('#'+ids).each(function(index1){
                selIndexes=selIndexes+"-"+this.value
            });
            valarr.push(ids+"~"+selIndexes);
            selIndexes = "";
         }

    });

    $('input[type="hidden"]').val(valarr);
}
$('input').click(function(){
    GetSelectedChks();
    alert ($('input[type="hidden"]').val());
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Great demo to find out on how to check my code.

Comment: Thanks a lot again. Here is my sample code and this is what I was trying to acheive. I could make it working by following your example and using a partial id selector. See my HTML and JS below.

Comment: HTML:
<form name="form1">
<input type="checkbox" name="selChk" value="5" id="UKAS-9ESDJV~APSE/Arun/Mgmt.nsf~5"> test 1
<input type="checkbox" name="selChk" value="4" id="UKAS-9ESDJV~APSE/Arun/Mgmt.nsf~4"> test 2
<input type="checkbox" name="selChk" value="6" id="UKAS-9ESDJV~APSE/Arun/Mgmt.nsf~6">test 3
<input type="checkbox" name="selChk" value="7" id="UKAS-9ESDJV~APSE/Arun/Mgmt.nsf~7">test 4
    <input type="text" value="" />
</form>

Comment: JS:function test() {
   *** same as above ****   
        if(this.name=='selChk' && ids.substring(0,ids.lastIndexOf("~"))!=this.id.substring(0,this.id.lastIndexOf("~")))
        {
            ids = this.id;
            tmp = "input[id^='"+ids.substring(0,ids.lastIndexOf("~"))+"']";
            
$(tmp).each(function(index1){
                selIndexes=selIndexes+"-"+this.value
            });
            *** same as above ****

Comment: it's great seeing you solved the problem! Happy coding!